# ffmpeg Flip video horizontally

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

anyone know can I make the video flip horizontal using batch file?

here my batch file code that I have tried :

```
@echo off

ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -vf hflip -i audio1.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Replaced Mp3\1.mp4"

pause
```

Comment: If you use a video filter you cannot use -c:v copy. You have to use an encoder or let ffmpeg decide default encoder.

Answer (score 5):

Minimally, your code should be:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i "input.mp3" -vf hflip -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest "output.mp4"
```

Note the order of where the video filter goes. `-vf` goes after the audio input in this code.

You can of course add your desired `-c:v` to something like `libx264` or similar, and add other parameters such as bitrates etc.

Comment: I would suggest you post your question separately with details of all parameters used, and at least a section of the console output shown by ffmeg.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would flip all MP4 videos in a folder and output it in a different folder in with a batch file from Windows 11, the full path were cut

```
for %%a in ("C:\Users\A-User-Name\Documents\movies\*.mp4") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf hflip -c:a copy "C:\Users\A-User-Name\Documents\movies\output\%%~na_hflip.mp4"
```

Note that for each and every input mp4, the output file name will be concatenated with "_hflip", which is achived using %%~na_hflip.mp4

I will save the above command in a .bat file and run it and it Work like a charm every time.